# How do I draw 3 colinear points only using a compass?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I know this is indeed possible because of the Mohr–Mascheroni theorem, and I thought about something like drawing two circles and looking at their intersection (for the 3rd point) but I have no idea how to prove that these points are indeed colinear.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Hexagon..

Comment: I you want to practice these constructions (and effectively prove the theorem) cut-the-knot has some nice scaling problems. http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/compass.shtml (The first one is basically this problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take two points, $A,B$. Draw the two circles with the segment $AB$ as a radius. The two circles intersect at points $C,D$. Draw the two circles with $CD$ as radius. They intersect at points $E,F$. $E,F$ are co-linear with $A,B$.